# Origini della parola "mafia"

Tags: etymology

Tutte le fonti di cui dispongo concordano nell'affremare che "mafia" è un termine di origine incerta, al punto che non è neanche chiaro quando sia stato introdotto in italiano. La voce di Wikipedia è un disastro. Il resto che circola su Internet è un'accozzaglia di teorie più o meno fantasiose, c'è chi addirittura ipotizza che derivi dal piemontese.

Esistono ipotesi accreditate sull'origine di questa parola?

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE, @imanoob!

Answer (score 9):

Nel complesso, pare che l'ipotesi più accreditata sia quella che fa risalire il termine “mafia”, attraverso tappe intermedie, all'arabo *maḥǰaṣ*, “millanteria”. Sono di questa opinione il [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/mafia), il Devoto-Oli (l'edizione cartacea che ho io specifica: «Dal siciliano *mafia*, ‘baldanza, braveria’, forse dall'arabo *maḥiaṣ*, ‘millanteria’; in origine voce tipica di Palermo, si è diffusa a partire dal 1863, a seguito del dramma dialettale di G[iuseppe] Rizzotto *I mafiusi della Vicaria*»), lo Zingarelli e, anch'esso con un “forse”, il classico Battisti-Alessio.

Il Treccani si limita a un «[etimo incerto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mafia/)», mentre il vecchio dizionario etimologico di Ottorino Pianigiani, disponibile in rete, come spesso accade è [più fantasioso](http://etimo.it/?term=mafia&find=Cerca).

Oltre al Devoto-Oli, anche le altre fonti che ho consultato fanno risalire la diffusione del termine agli anni '60 dell'Ottocento.

Un'ipotesi lievemente diversa appare in *FAQ Mafia* di Attilio Bolzoni (Bompiani, 2010): «Quasi certamente ha la sua etimologia nell'espressione araba *maha fat* che vuol dire protezione, immunità».
Bolzoni aggiunge che la prima comparsa ufficiale della parola “mafia” risale al 25 aprile 1865, in un rapporto del prefetto di Palermo, Filippo Antonio Gualterio, al ministro degli Interni (mentre il termine non compare mai, al di fuori dei *mafiusi* del titolo, nel testo della citata pièce di Rizzotto).

Comment: Fra l'altro, com'è noto, la Mafia stessa per riferirsi a sé stessa non usa questa parola, ma "Cosa Nostra".

Answer (score 3):

La [consulenza linguistica dell'Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/camorra-mafia-ndrangheta--parte-ii-origine-di-mafia/869) riporta lo studio di Alberto Nocentini a proposito dell'origine di *mafia*.

L'articolo mi sembra interessante perché spiega i problemi che ha l'ipotesi segnalata come la più accreditata nella risposta di @DaG e aggiunge qualche altra ipotesi.
Indica anche in che momento questo vocabolo è stato introdotto nella lessicografia.

Il termine *mafia* si comincia a usare nel periodo postunitario:

> La comparsa di *mafia* è più o meno coeva a quella di *camorra*, ma priva di precedenti anteriori al periodo postunitario: attraverso il derivato *mafioso* figura nel testo teatrale di Giuseppe Rizzotto *I mafiusi di la Vicaria di Palermu* (1863) e la sua registrazione ufficiale nella lessicografia si deve al *Nuovo vocabolario siciliano-italiano* di Antonino Traina (Palermo, 1868-1873) coi significati di ‘braveria, baldanza, tracotanza, pottata, spocchia’ e infine ‘nome collettivo di tutti i mafiosi’.

Esistono diverse ipotesi per l'etimologia.
Una è stata già menzionata nella risposta di @DaG:

> La presenza di una -*f*- in posizione interna, estranea alla tradizione latina, e la sua peculiarità di voce siciliana, hanno indirizzato la ricerca delle origini verso l’arabo e in questa direzione, la proposta che riscuote più consensi è quella dell’adattamento del prestito *maḥyāṣ* ‘smargiasso’, col derivato *maḥyaṣa* ‘smargiassata millanteria’, nella riformulazione di Salvatore Trovato (*Atti del XXI Congresso Internazionale di Linguistica e Filologia Romanza*, Vol. III, Tübingen, Niemeyer, 1998, pp. 919-925).

Un'altra ipotesi basata anche nella congettura che si tratti di un arabismo è la seguente:

> Meno fortunata, ma non per questo meno degna di considerazione, è la proposta avanzata a suo tempo da G.M. Da Aleppo e G.M. Calvaruso (*Le fonti arabiche del dialetto siciliano. Vocabolario etimologico*, Roma, Loescher, 1910) e rilanciata con qualche correzione da M. Salem Elsheikh (*Gli interscambi culturali e socio-economici fra l’Africa Settentrionale e l’Europa mediterranea*, Napoli, 1986, pp. 943-951), secondo la quale mafia sarebbe la resa dell’arabismo *mo’afiah* ‘arroganza, tracotanza, prevaricazione’. Se dovessimo propendere per l’arabismo, questa seconda ipotesi ci sembrerebbe preferibile, perché comporta un adattamento minimo in quanto il segmento iniziale *mo’a*– si riduce facilmente a *ma*–.

Queste ipotesi, però, presentano certi problemi:

> Ma le difficoltà dell’arabismo sono altre, prima di tutte la datazione: è difficile accettare una trasmissione sotterranea di almeno otto secoli, se si attribuisce il prestito al periodo della dominazione araba della Sicilia, e d’altra parte, se si sostiene la sua adozione recente, si ha l’obbligo di indicarne e motivarne il tramite attraverso i documenti. 
> Bisogna poi tener conto di due fatti di ordine semantico: il primo è che gli scrittori siciliani del secondo Ottocento sono concordi nel sostenere che in Sicilia il significato primitivo di *mafia* era ‘eleganza, braveria, eccellenza’; il secondo è che fuori di Sicilia la voce è diffusa nei dialetti centro-meridionali col significato di ‘spocchia’ e prevalentemente nella variante *maffia* con doppia -*f*-.

Ulteriori ricerche hanno dato luogo ad altri indizi e a un'altra interessante ipotesi:

> Una ricerca più accurata fa emergere il bergamasco *mafia* “donna di età mezzana”, l’elbano *maffiona* ‘(donna) colla faccia piena e tonda’ e la locuzione *far (la) maffia* ‘sfoggiare lusso’, propria del gergo militare. Al maschile troviamo il torinese *mafi*, *mafiu* ‘tanghero’ e il milanese *brüt mafee* ‘uomo brutto’, che Angelico Prati (*Voci di gerganti, vagabondi e malviventi*, Supplem. II a *L’Italia Dialettale*, 1940, pp. 125-128) riconduce senza difficoltà al nome proprio *Maffeo*, variante di *Matteo*, appartenente alla serie dei nomi biblici in -*èo*, che hanno acquisito un significato dispregiativo, descritti a suo tempo da Bruno Migliorini (*Dal nome proprio al nome comune*, Genève, Olschki, 1927, pp. 274-275). La stessa origine il Prati attribuisce di conseguenza alle voci femminili citate sopra, ma questa sua conclusione ha incontrato scarsa approvazione.
> Vale invece la pena d’insistere sull’origine del nome proprio *Maffeo* per almeno tre buone ragioni: fornisce una base lessicale accertata *maf(f)*-, altrimenti estranea al lessico italiano, rende conto dell’oscillazione -*f*-*l*-*ff*- tipica dei nomi propri che derivano da *Matthaeus*, permette di vedere nella Sicilia un centro di espansione recenziore della voce nella sua accezione più nota, ma non necessariamente il luogo della sua formazione. Stando ai dati forniti dai dialetti italiani, *maf(f)ia* è in partenza una *vox media* che significa ‘braveria, baldanza’, suscettibile di assumere accezioni positive o negative secondo l’etica e il costume dei parlanti: così in Sicilia, dove l’esibizione delle proprie ricchezze e del proprio stato sociale elevato è considerato un comportamento legittimo e naturale, la voce ha preso il significato di ‘eleganza, eccellenza’, mentre in Toscana, dove è vista come un’ostentazione inopportuna da guardare persino con sospetto, ha preso quello di ‘spocchia, boria’. 
> Il nodo mancante è quello che lega questo comportamento al nome di *Maffeo* e il personaggio di riferimento non può che essere l’apostolo *Matteo*. A guardar bene nel racconto della sua conversione secondo il Vangelo di Luca ci sono tutti gli elementi utili, considerando non tanto il suo significato profondo quanto piuttosto le reazioni prodotte nell’immaginazione e nei sentimenti dell’uditorio. A differenza degli altri apostoli, semplici pescatori che avevano seguito Gesù senza cerimonie, Matteo, da ricco pubblicano, solennizza l’avvenimento con un atto di magnificenza: "Poi Levi gli preparò un grande banchetto nella sua casa. C’era una folla di pubblicani e d’altra gente seduta con loro a tavola" (Luca 5, 29). Per gli ascoltatori delle letture domenicali questi elementi erano più che sufficienti a caratterizzare il tipo che trasforma un evento personale in un’esibizione di lusso e di superiorità, che *fa la maffia*. 
> Del resto il Vangelo di Luca è il più ricco di particolari narrativi, recepiti e rielaborati sia dalla tradizione dotta che da quella popolare, come le figure del *ricco epulone*, prototipo del gaudente dissoluto, e del povero Lazzaro, prototipo dello straccione miserabile, che ha dato il napoletano (e italiano) *lazzarone* ‘pezzente, vagabondo, canaglia’. Un riflesso dell’immagine popolare dell’apostolo Matteo, conseguenza della sua magnificenza, si coglie con evidenza in un detto che mi è stato riferito da un informatore di Torremaggiore (Foggia): quando qualcuno a tavola si abbuffa oltre misura, si usa rimproverarlo dicendo *eh, Sande Mattèe!*